# Return the heading of the column in which a cell contains a given word

Tags: google-sheets

Setup:
Row 1: Headings

Row 2: Names where each cell contains several names.

Problem:
I want to check if row n contains "Tom" and return the corresponding heading. I don't want to use helping cells since I have to do this for a huge amount of names.

I tried query and hlookup. Further i tried to use regex together with an arrayformuar. But Nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
=filter(A$1:F$1, regexmatch(A2:F2, "Joe"))
```

returns any headings where the content of the 2nd row contains "Joe", case-sensitive.

The following subtly different formula (with + before `filter`) returns only the first such heading:

```
=+filter(A$1:F$1, regexmatch(A2:F2, "Joe"))
```